# Console download accelerator that downloads *multiple* files simultaneously

Tags: ftp, web, download

The download accelerators I've found thus far only let me specify a single file to download. This is useful for single large files, but I'm looking for a tool that lets me hand over a *list* of multiple files to download simultaneously.

In some cases I would want to download the entire list in the traditional accelerated fashion, but sometimes I wouldn't want acceleration - for example, when I was fetching script-generated content.

**EDIT**: `lftp` is quite a good program (!), but has no way to show live information about ***all*** running downloads, only one (via `wait all`). I *can* write a script which watches `lftp`'s file descriptors and displays statistics off of that, but that's decidedly inelegant... and thinking about it, I don't know how big the downloaded file is (since I have no access to the `lftp` process) so I can't calculate percentages anyway. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lftp` can do that.

You've got:

- `pget` to download a single file with several connections
- `mirror -P 4` to download a tree with up to four connections
- and you can put any `get` in background to start another one with `get file &`  (also <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> to put a download in background when using it interactively).

You can set the number of connections per site with:

```
set net:connection-limit 6
```

Use the `jobs` command to see the status of the download(s).

`lftp` supports a number of protocols including HTTP, FTP, SFTP and is scriptable (`#! /usr/bin/lftp -f`, or `lftp -c commands`).

Comment: That's awesome!!1 Thanks :D Time to read the manual.... ^^