# Multi-file simultaneous downloader with live statistics for all files

Tags: command-line, ftp, web, download

*<sub>(I recently asked the question "[Console download accelerator that downloads *multiple* files simultaneously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113813/console-download-accelerator-that-downloads-multiple-files-simultaneously)" and learned about `lftp`, an excellent program which can download multiple files simultaneously, however it does this in the background - to the extent that it's impossible to know the status of the backgrounded downloads. Since I didn't clarify that I wanted live updating in that question, I'm starting a new one.)</sub>*

I frequently download batches of URLs at the console and a currently do this by launching several `wget` instances simultaneously. The subsequent console output is quite a mess, and what's more, it's difficult to know when the processes have finished (because the `wget` instances were started in the background and my shell prompt, which "returned back to me" instantly, was overwritten long ago).

I'm looking for a program which can download more than one file, at the console, and show live download statistics for each file. It doesn't actually have to be an accelerator as such - just a "multi-downloader". (I kinda got the terminology confused before.)